# p5.js oscillator showing multiple waveform

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In the p5.js oscillator provided example multiple waveform are drawn, how can we make it appear as single?
The example is here:
https://p5js.org/examples/sound-oscillator-frequency.html
Below is also the code:

```js
let osc, fft;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 256);

  osc = new p5.TriOsc(); // set frequency and type
  osc.amp(0.5);

  fft = new p5.FFT();
  osc.start();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  let waveform = fft.waveform(); // analyze the waveform
  beginShape();
  strokeWeight(5);
  for (let i = 0; i < waveform.length; i++) {
    let x = map(i, 0, waveform.length, 0, width);
    let y = map(waveform[i], -1, 1, height, 0);
    vertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape();

  // change oscillator frequency based on mouseX
  let freq = map(mouseX, 0, width, 40, 880);
  osc.freq(freq);

  let amp = map(mouseY, 0, height, 1, 0.01);
  osc.amp(amp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```